# Why assigning a macro (Sub) to a Button is not working from a separate module , although it works if I put it on (ThisOutlookSession)?

Tags: vba, automation, outlook, email-attachments, ribbonx

`I am using the below code to`: Save all attachments of the selected items to the hard disk. 
The path assigned to the Path variable must yet exist. 
The macro automatically creates a subfolder in that directory named with the current date. 
Eventually the Windows file explorer will be opened with that new directory. 
**Problem**, If I put the below code on a separate module then assign it to a custom button on the ribbon, 
Then click on that button ,the result is nothing executed at all with no error raised, **although** if I run it from code window, it works gracefully. 
**Also** , if I moved all the sub to (`ThisOutlookSession`) and assign it to a button ,the result is macro working from that button correctly. 
So, my question is How to keep this code on a separate module and make it run from a button on the ribbon?

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments2()
  Dim coll As VBA.Collection
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim Att As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim Sel As Outlook.Selection
  Dim Path$
  Dim i&
 
  Path = "d:\"
  Path = Path & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "\"
  On Error Resume Next
  MkDir Path
  On Error GoTo 0
 
  Set coll = New VBA.Collection
 
  If TypeOf Application.ActiveWindow Is Outlook.Inspector Then
    coll.Add Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
  Else
    Set Sel = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    For i = 1 To Sel.Count
      coll.Add Sel(i)
    Next
  End If
 
  For Each obj In coll
    For Each Att In obj.Attachments
      Att.SaveAsFile Path & Att.FileName
    Next
  Next
 
  Shell "Explorer.exe /n, /e, " & Path, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you add the button on the Ribbon? How do you assign the macro, even from a standard module? When I played with such an issue, I never had a problem with running the assigned macro, even if it was placed in a standard module. Is it a matter of not doing some specific tasks or it is not able to run any macro? Please, try creating a simple macro like: `Sub MyMacroToBeCalled()` `MsgBox "I've been called..."` `End Sub` and assign it to a button on Ribbon (QAT or a Tab). Can you call it pressing the newly added button? I played in Outlook 2016/365...

Comment: @FaneDuru , obviously used `customize ribbon` to add the button (surly not the same shape like excel).
Also , I have other subs on a another separate modules and linked to a button on (custom group on the ribbon) and works correctly.
Except the sub on my question whom cannot run from the button.
The provided answer by @Eugene Astafiev works , but it is a workaround and not a solution.

Comment: Please, place a break point on the line `Path = "d:\"`. Does the code reach it, when press the button in discussion? If yes, try running the code line by line and see where it stops. It may be a kind of security issue in case of some code lines looking dangerous...

Comment: @FaneDuru , I deleted the calling proxy sub from `ThisOutlookSession`,
then I created another button on ribbon and linked to the main sub (found on a separate module).
**strangely** it now works correctly, I do not know why it is now working.
Thanks FaneDuru for your keen to solve the issue.
@Eugene Astafiev ,using your answer for only one time solved the issue (I still do not know how).

Comment: I do not know what to say, too. I could try an explanation if you would try my suggestion without calling the sub from `ThisOutlookSession`... If it is a matter of security, maybe Outlook placed the sub in a kind of 'Trusted macros` equivalent. I did not hear about such a behavior, anyhow.

Comment: @FaneDuru , sure I tried your suggestion without calling the sub from ThisOutlookSession , that why I was stranged that it works, anyhow I am happy as it now working and my sub still clear and organized.

Comment: But, if you tested it before calling the function from `ThisOutlookSession`, was the macro called? Did it reach the breakpoint? If so, at which line did the code stop? I suppose, if it worked well, was no reason to try calling from `ThisOutlookSession`, I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your original sub in any module, but use a proxy from the `ThisOutlookSession` file to call it when it is invoked by the QAT button.

By default, only the default `ThisOutlookSession` module is monitored by Outlook for subs that can be assigned to QAT buttons.

Comment: But, I already have another codes on a sperate subs and assigned to QAT buttons and works normally without use a proxy from the ThisOutlookSession.

Comment: People would like to get a ready-made solution, but I am not a service for delivering. I am just trying to help others. Users need to have skills or knowledge to apply everything that is written in the answers or posts. That's why some posts are not accepted.